# I am having trouble performing an NFS mount of a Solaris filesystem on a Ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu, mount, solaris, nfs

I am trying to do an NFS mount of a Solaris (version 5.10) file system
(on a Sun Blade 2500) on a Ubuntu (release 20.04) system (on a Dell
Precision Tower 3620).  My (possibly incorrect) understanding is that this should be
doable.  See, for example [this](https://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.com/2014/02/mounting-solaris-nfs-share-on-linux.html)

I am going to describe my set-up and what I did to perform the
connection.  My question is:  Can you see/guess what I am doing wrong,
and suggest a fix.

I have a direct ethernet cable link between the two machines.  Via
this link I can ping each machine from the other.  Via this link I can
telnet and ftp from the Ubuntu machine to the Solaris machine.

The IP address of the Sun is 128.104.77.240.

The IP address of the Dell is 128.104.77.239.

In the `/etc/dfs/dfstab` file on the Sun I have

```
share -F nfs -o rw=128.104.77.239 /export/home
```

In the `/etc/dfs/sharetab` file on the Sun I have

```
/export/home - nfs rw=128.104.77.239
```

On the Sun I did:

```
svcadm -v disable network/nfs/server
svcadm -v enable network/nfs/server
shareall
```

On the Dell I made sure that NFS client capability was available by doing:

```
sudo apt install nfs-common
```

On the Dell I did

```
sudo mount -vt nfs 128.104.77.240:/export/home /home/user/test
```

and got

```
[sudo] password for user:
```

which I provided.

I then got

```
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sat Mar 19 16:51:55 2022
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=128.104.77.240,clientaddr=128.104.77.239'
mount.nfs: mount(2): Input/output error
mount.nfs: mount system call failed
```

Any suggestions/guesses???

In response to Andrew:  3/25/22, 6:42
Run on dell (Ubuntu machine, 128.104.77.239):

```
showmount -e 128.104.77.240
```

yields
Export list for 128.104.77.240:

```
/export/home/test 128.104.77.239
```

In response to Romeo:  I altered the Sun /etc/default/nfs file so that the NFS version was 3.

An example of the results that I then obtained is:

```
root@user-Precision-Tower-3620:/home/user# mount -vt nfs 128.104.77.240:/export/home/test /home/steve2/mount_test

mount.nfs: timeout set for Fri Mar 25 16:03:36 2022

mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=128.104.77.240,clientaddr=128.104.77.239'

mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported

mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.1,addr=128.104.77.240,clientaddr=128.104.77.239'

mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported

mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.0,addr=128.104.77.240,clientaddr=128.104.77.239'  

mount.nfs: mount(2): Protocol not supported

mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'addr=128.104.77.240'  

mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6  
mount.nfs: trying 128.104.77.240 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049

mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17  
mount.nfs: trying 128.104.77.240 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 32781

mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied

mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 128.104.77.240:/export/home/test
```

Comment: Try to set server to use NFS v3

Comment: Thank you very much Romeo for editing my question.  I will look into your suggestion.   Best regards,  Steve.

Comment: Also, post the output of `showmount -e 128.104.77.240` run from your Ubuntu system.

Comment: From ubuntu, you can use `rpcinfo -m 128.104.77.240`, which will show you if the nfs services are all running and reachable from the Ubuntu host. (It won’t attempt to connect to them all, but will query the portmapper)

Comment: Thank you Andrew and Tim.